# Add namespace to kubernetes hostname

Tags: kubernetes

Currently my pods are all named "some-deployment-foo-bar" which does not help me track down issues when an error is reported with just the hostname.

So I want "$POD_NAMESPACE.$POD_NAME" as hostname.

I tried `pod.beta.kubernetes.io/hostname: "foo"` but that only sets an absolute name ... and subdomain did not work ...

The only other solution I saw was using a wrapper script that modifies the hostname and then executes the actual command ... which is pretty hacky and adds overhead ot every container.

Any way of doing this nicely?

current config is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
  labels:
    project: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      project: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      name: foo
      labels:
        project: foo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        name: foo
```

Comment: can you share your deployment config file?

Comment: updated ... not sure if that is very helpful ... it's bare-bone ...

Comment: when you say you want `$POD_NAMESPACE.$POD_NAME` as a hostname, do you mean for access. I.E. ping the pod by this URL?

Comment: I don't care about pinging, just for what the host reports as it's hostname since that is uses by various monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

PodSpec has a subdomain field, which can be used to specify the Pod’s subdomain. This field value takes precedence over the pod.beta.kubernetes.io/subdomain annotation value.

[There is more information here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records-and-hostname-based-on-pods-hostname-and-subdomain-fields), below is an example.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: default-subdomain
    spec:
      selector:
        name: busybox
      clusterIP: None
      ports:
        - name: foo # Actually, no port is needed.
          port: 1234 
          targetPort: 1234
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: busybox1
      labels:
        name: busybox
    spec:
      hostname: busybox-1
      subdomain: default-subdomain
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        command:
          - sleep
          - "3600"
        name: busybox
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: busybox2
      labels:
        name: busybox
    spec:
      hostname: busybox-2
      subdomain: default-subdomain
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        command:
          - sleep
          - "3600"
        name: busybox
```

Comment: My issue is for a Deployment, no a single Pod ... tried this and did not work, hostname and pod name are still unchanged.

Comment: To be clear: 
1) hostname works, but then it's hardcoded .. would need it to be still different per pod since we have multiple replicas
2) subdomain works, but does not change the hostname, just the `hostname --fqdn`